# Navigation menu clicks issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I have a menu which works perfectly, but the problem is on-click on 'depth-level-2 sub-menu','depth-level-3' should open then 'depth-level-0' should move left. When it in the first iteration its works fine but the 2nd time it's not working.

#### To reproduce,

Click

**menu-item-1** then **menu-item-1.2** --> **menu-item-1.2.2** then **menu-item-1.2.2.2** it opens it's sub menu and '**menu-item-1.2's sub-menu**' moves to left perfectly but **if I repeat this process again it not working.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.afs-menu-item').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
   $('.afs-dropdown',this).slideToggle(300).animate({'left':'0px'});
    $('.afs-col ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find(".afs-dropdown").hide();     
  });
  
  /*sub-col-1.2*/
  $('.afs-col ul li').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find("li").removeClass('active');
        
     //$('.sub-col li').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).children().find(".sub-sub-sub-col").hide();
    
  });
  
  /*sub-sub-col*/
  $('.afs-col ul li ul').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  
  
   $('.afs-sub-sub-col > ul > li').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
     console.log(clicks);
      if (clicks==true) {
        $('.afs-dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '0px'
        })     
      }
      else {
        $('.afs-dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '-510px'
        })
      }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
  
  /*sub-sub-sub-col*/
   $('.afs-col ul ul li ul').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
 
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*Container
===============*/

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.afs-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.afs-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #00A0F0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.afs-dropdown li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #00A0F0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.afs-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.afs-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0;   
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}

.afs-dropdown > .afs-col {
  display: block;  
}


.visible {
  display: block;
}

.afs-col {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
}


.afs-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}


.afs-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;  
}

.afs-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;

}
.afs-sub-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.active .afs-col {
  display: block;
}
.afs-col .active .afs-sub-col{
  display: block;
}

.afs-col .afs-sub-col .active .afs-sub-sub-col {
  display: block;
}
 .afs-col .afs-sub-col .afs-sub-sub-col .active .afs-sub-sub-sub-col{
  display: block;
}


.iva-children-indenter {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #00A0F0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.iva-children-indenter-2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: #00A0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul class="afs-menu">
        <li class="afs-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-1</a> 
          <div class="afs-dropdown">
            <div class="afs-col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.1</a></li>
                <li class="deeper-nav"><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.2<span class="iva-children-indenter"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                    <div class="afs-sub-col">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                            <div class="afs-sub-sub-col">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                                  <div class="afs-sub-sub-sub-col">
                                    <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  </a></li>
                               </ul>
                            </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                          </a></li>   
                        </ul>
                      </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.4</a></li>
               </ul>
              </div>  <!--col-->  
             </div><!--dropdown-->
         </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-2</a>
          <div class="afs-dropdown">
            <div class="afs-col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.2 <span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>       
                  <div class="afs-sub-col">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">menuitem2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="afs-sub-sub-col">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2">
                              <div class="afs-sub-sub-sub-col">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                              </a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                        </a></li>   
                    </ul>
                  </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  <!--col-->  
           </div><!--dropdown-->
        </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-3</a></a>
        </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-4</a></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--inner-->
</div><!--container-->
```

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/bharathkumar_sriram/pen/wqyRbR)

Comment: Its working just fine.

Comment: The first time it's working 2nd time it's not working.

Comment: @BharathKumar completed. Answered. you're missing a bit of code while setting data attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the data attribute `clicks` to false on every `.afs-menu-item` clicks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.afs-menu-item').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
   $('.afs-dropdown',this).slideToggle(300).animate({'left':'0px'});
    $('.afs-col ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find(".afs-dropdown").hide(); 

    //Reset data attr here
    $(this).data('clicks',false);


  });
  
  /*sub-col-1.2*/
  $('.afs-col ul li').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find("li").removeClass('active');
        
     //$('.sub-col li').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).children().find(".sub-sub-sub-col").hide();
    
  });
  
  /*sub-sub-col*/
  $('.afs-col ul li ul').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  
  
   $('.afs-sub-sub-col > ul > li').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
  var clicks = $(this).parents('.afs-menu-item').data('clicks');
     console.log(clicks);
      if (clicks==true) {
        $('.afs-dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '0px'
        })     
      }
      else {
        $('.afs-dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '-510px'
        })
      }
  $(this).parents('.afs-menu-item').data("clicks", !clicks);
});
  
  /*sub-sub-sub-col*/
   $('.afs-col ul ul li ul').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
 
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*Container
===============*/

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.afs-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.afs-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #00A0F0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.afs-dropdown li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #00A0F0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.afs-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.afs-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0;   
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}

.afs-dropdown > .afs-col {
  display: block;  
}


.visible {
  display: block;
}

.afs-col {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
}


.afs-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}


.afs-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;  
}

.afs-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;

}
.afs-sub-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.active .afs-col {
  display: block;
}
.afs-col .active .afs-sub-col{
  display: block;
}

.afs-col .afs-sub-col .active .afs-sub-sub-col {
  display: block;
}
 .afs-col .afs-sub-col .afs-sub-sub-col .active .afs-sub-sub-sub-col{
  display: block;
}


.iva-children-indenter {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #00A0F0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.iva-children-indenter-2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: #00A0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul class="afs-menu">
        <li class="afs-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-1</a> 
          <div class="afs-dropdown">
            <div class="afs-col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.1</a></li>
                <li class="deeper-nav"><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.2<span class="iva-children-indenter"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                    <div class="afs-sub-col">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                            <div class="afs-sub-sub-col">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                                  <div class="afs-sub-sub-sub-col">
                                    <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  </a></li>
                               </ul>
                            </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                          </a></li>   
                        </ul>
                      </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.4</a></li>
               </ul>
              </div>  <!--col-->  
             </div><!--dropdown-->
         </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-2</a>
          <div class="afs-dropdown">
            <div class="afs-col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.2 <span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>       
                  <div class="afs-sub-col">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">menuitem2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="afs-sub-sub-col">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2">
                              <div class="afs-sub-sub-sub-col">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                              </a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                        </a></li>   
                    </ul>
                  </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  <!--col-->  
           </div><!--dropdown-->
        </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-3</a></a>
        </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-4</a></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--inner-->
</div><!--container-->
```

Comment: That works but I had it already. Now it is not working on even clicks like 2,4,6 and so on.

Comment: The problem was when the menu click happens the node with the data attribute `clicks` is not present, to solve that added the data-attr `clicks` to the parent `.afs-menu-item`, I've updated my answer as well take a look

Comment: I had a small issue.On click on menu items, the sub-menus are toggling perfectly. But the sub-menus are showing their sub-menus too.

Comment: I'm not getting it?

Comment: On click 'menu-item 1.2' its 'sub-menu 1.2.2 'is opening. On click 'menu-item 1.2.2' its 'sub-menu 1.2.2.2 'is opening.But if i again click on 'menu-item-1.2' both submenus like 1.2.2 and 1.2.2.2 are showing.But it should show only menu 1.2.2 it should not show menu-item-1.2.2.2

Comment: One way to solve that would be instead of hiding and showing try removing the whole siblings and start it from step1

Comment: I understand it should be done from scratch. But is there any possibility to fix it temporarily.

Comment: we can set flags or data attr to differentiate but again that will require more effort than removing and adding

Answer (score 0):

For first time, `console.log(clicks);` logs `undefined`.

So, change this line

```
$(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
```

to

```
$(this).data("clicks", clicks==undefined?false:!clicks);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('.afs-menu-item').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
   $('.afs-dropdown',this).slideToggle(300).animate({'left':'0px'});
    $('.afs-col ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find(".afs-dropdown").hide();     
  });
  
  /*sub-col-1.2*/
  $('.afs-col ul li').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find("li").removeClass('active');
        
     //$('.sub-col li').removeClass('active');
    //$(this).children().find(".sub-sub-sub-col").hide();
    
  });
  
  /*sub-sub-col*/
  $('.afs-col ul li ul').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  
  
   $('.afs-sub-sub-col > ul > li').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
     console.log(clicks);
      if (clicks==true) {
        $('.afs-dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '0px'
        })     
      }
      else {
        $('.afs-dropdown').animate({
             'left' : '-510px'
        })
      }
  $(this).data("clicks", clicks==undefined?false:!clicks);
});
  
  /*sub-sub-sub-col*/
   $('.afs-col ul ul li ul').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
 
});
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Mada', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/*Container
===============*/

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.afs-menu {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.afs-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #00A0F0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.afs-dropdown li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #00A0F0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
.afs-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.afs-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0;   
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    display: none;
}

.afs-dropdown > .afs-col {
  display: block;  
}


.visible {
  display: block;
}

.afs-col {  
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 33%;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 99;
}


.afs-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
.afs-sub-sub-sub-col > ul > li {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}


.afs-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;  
}

.afs-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;

}
.afs-sub-sub-sub-col {
  position: absolute;
  left: 510px;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.active .afs-col {
  display: block;
}
.afs-col .active .afs-sub-col{
  display: block;
}

.afs-col .afs-sub-col .active .afs-sub-sub-col {
  display: block;
}
 .afs-col .afs-sub-col .afs-sub-sub-col .active .afs-sub-sub-sub-col{
  display: block;
}


.iva-children-indenter {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: #00A0F0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.iva-children-indenter-2{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 30%;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: #00A0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <ul class="afs-menu">
        <li class="afs-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-1</a> 
          <div class="afs-dropdown">
            <div class="afs-col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.1</a></li>
                <li class="deeper-nav"><a href="#">Menu-item: 1.2<span class="iva-children-indenter"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span></a>
                    <div class="afs-sub-col">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                            <div class="afs-sub-sub-col">
                              <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menuitem1.2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                                  <div class="afs-sub-sub-sub-col">
                                    <ul>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                  </a></li>
                               </ul>
                            </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                          </a></li>   
                        </ul>
                      </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item-1.4</a></li>
               </ul>
              </div>  <!--col-->  
             </div><!--dropdown-->
         </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item"><a href="#">Menu-item-2</a>
          <div class="afs-dropdown">
            <div class="afs-col">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu-item: 2.2 <span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>       
                  <div class="afs-sub-col">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">menuitem2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2"><i class="fa fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="afs-sub-sub-col">
                          <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Menuitem2.2.2.2<span class="iva-children-indenter-2">
                              <div class="afs-sub-sub-sub-col">
                                <ul>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.1</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">menuitem1.2.2.2.2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                              </div>
                              </a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div><!--sub-sub-col-->
                        </a></li>   
                    </ul>
                  </div><!--sub-col-->
                  </a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>  <!--col-->  
           </div><!--dropdown-->
        </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-3</a></a>
        </li>
        <li class="afs-menu-item">
          <a href="#"><a href="#">Menu-item-4</a></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--inner-->
</div><!--container-->
```

Comment: That worked but odd clicks like 3,5,7 menu animation not working.